# PIVOT SQL returning duplicate rows for weekdays

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with some  data which looks like:

```
+-----+-------------+---------------------+----------+-----------+ 
| id  |    name     |        date         |  start   |    end    | 
+-----+-------------+---------------------+----------+-----------+ 
| 123 | marsGuy     | 2018-01-03 00:00:00 | 10:00:00 | 16:00:00  | 
| 123 | marsGUy     | 2018-01-04 00:00:00 | 10:00:00 | 12:00:00  | 
| 124 | snickersGuy | 2018-01-03 00:00:00 | 10:00:00 | 18:00:00  | 
+-----+-------------+---------------------+----------+-----------+
```

I currently using PIVOT SQL and trying to pull data and produce individual columns from Fri-Thur and show the amount of hours a person work within that week. So for the above, I want `marsGuy` into one row because he's working 2 shifts in the same week if you take a look at his corresponding date column.

Based on some rules in the case statement in the query below, I want them to have certain words after calculating how many hours they worked.

So if they did 8 hours (or above) their row under that specific day will be filled with the word 'highAf' like below:

```
+-------------+-----+-----+-----+--------+-------+-----+------+
|    name     | fri | sat | sun |  mon   |  tue  | wed | thur |
+-------------+-----+-----+-----+--------+-------+-----+------+
| marsGuy     |     |     |     | good   | small |     |      |
| snickersGuy |     |     |     | highAf |       |     |      |
+-------------+-----+-----+-----+--------+-------+-----+------+
```

The query:

```
select distinct
    name,
    posId,
    [6] as Fri,
    [7] as Sat,
    [1] as Sun,
    [2] as Mon,
    [3] as Tue,
    [4] as Wed,
    [5] as Thu
from 
(
select
    case 
        when DATEDIFF(HOUR, start, end) >= 8.5 then 'highAf'
        when DATEDIFF(HOUR, start, end) >= 6.5 then 'good' 
        when DATEDIFF(HOUR, start, end) >= 4 then  'moderate'
        when DATEDIFF(HOUR, start end) >= 2 then 'small'
    end as hourWorked,
    datepart(weekday, date) as day_of_week
from MyTable

) as p pivot
( max(hourWorked) for day_of_week in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7])
) as pivottbl
```

I think i'm really close. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think you are confused about what `datediff()` does.  It returns an integer, so comparing to 6.5 is exactly the same as comparing to 7.

Comment: What's wrong with your current query?

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work by selecting `name` and ensuring `name` was selected in the sub-query.  For example:

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE (id int, [name] varchar(100), [date] datetime, [start] time(0), [end] time(0))
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES
 (123, 'marsGuy',     '2018-01-03 00:00:00', '10:00:00', '16:00:00')
,(123, 'marsGUy',     '2018-01-04 00:00:00', '10:00:00', '12:00:00')    
,(124, 'snickersGuy', '2018-01-03 00:00:00', '10:00:00', '18:00:00')
,(124, 'snickersGuy', '2018-01-01 00:00:00', '10:00:00', '19:00:00')

select distinct
    [name],
    --posId,
    [6] as Fri,
    [7] as Sat,
    [1] as Sun,
    [2] as Mon,
    [3] as Tue,
    [4] as Wed,
    [5] as Thu
from 
(
select
    [name],
    case 
        when DATEDIFF(MINUTE, [start], [end]) >= 510 then 'highAf'
        when DATEDIFF(MINUTE, [start], [end]) >= 390 then 'good' 
        when DATEDIFF(MINUTE, [start], [end]) >= 240 then  'moderate'
        when DATEDIFF(MINUTE, [start], [end]) >= 120 then 'small'
    end as hourWorked,
    datepart(weekday, date) as day_of_week
from @MyTable

) as p pivot
( max(hourWorked) for day_of_week in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7])
) as pivottbl
```

Produces output:

```
name        Fri  Sat  Sun  Mon    Tue  Wed      Thu
marsGuy     NULL NULL NULL NULL   NULL moderate small
snickersGuy NULL NULL NULL highAf NULL good     NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `apply` :

```
select name, max(case when day_of_week = 1 then hourWorked end),
             max(case when day_of_week = 2 then hourWorked end),
             max(case when day_of_week = 3 then hourWorked end),
             max(case when day_of_week = 4 then hourWorked end),
             max(case when day_of_week = 5 then hourWorked end),
             max(case when day_of_week = 6 then hourWorked end),
             max(case when day_of_week = 7 then hourWorked end)
from MyTable t cross apply
     ( values ( (case when DATEDIFF(HOUR, start, [end]) >= 8.5 then 'highAf'
                      when DATEDIFF(HOUR, start, [end]) >= 6.5 then 'good' 
                      when DATEDIFF(HOUR, start, [end]) >= 4   then 'moderate'
                      when DATEDIFF(HOUR, start, [end]) >= 2   then 'small' 
                  end), datepart(WEEKDAY, [date])   
              )
     ) tt (hourWorked, day_of_week)
group by name;
```